# Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, field

I am facing the Uncaught **TypeError : Cannot read property 'length' of undefined** in the output console while running the following code using JavaScript:

```
var field = [];

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(625, 625);
    field = generateField();    
}

function draw()
{
    background(51);

    for(var i=0; i<field.length; i++)
    {
        field[i].draw();
    }
}

function generateField()
{
    var f = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 625; i++)
    {
        f.push(new Tile(i%25, Math.floor(i/25), "BARRIER"));
    }
}
```

The error is coming in the line: for(var i=0; i < field.length; i++)

Any suggestions on how to debug this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: `field = generateField(); ` but `generateField` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most probably just missing a return statement in this function:

```
function generateField()
{
    var f = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 625; i++)
    {
        f.push(new Tile(i%25, Math.floor(i/25), "BARRIER"));
    }
    return f;      // <-- this line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `return` statement on the `generateField` function and as it is explained on [Functions - JavaScript|MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions):

> A `function` without a `return` statement will return a default value. In the case of a `constructor` called with the `new` keyword, the `default` value is the value of its `this` parameter. For all other functions, the default `return` value is `undefined`.

In this case, `generateField` is being used as a regular function and it will returns `undefined`. Because of this, an `Uncaught TypeError` is thrown when trying to access a `length` property on the `field` variable.